# How can I export Shared Outlook Calendars?

Tags: c#, outlook, calendar, export, exchange-server

I am looking for a solution to export Shared Outlook Calendars (yes, I'm using exchange server and yes I can copy calendar to my local folders, which would allow me to export. However, what if there are more than 50 calendars, which I need to export? Is there a way of automating the process?).

I am interested in using C# for accomplish this task. Has anyone ever tried to do that?

Answer (score 1):

[Exchange Web Services (EWS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119(EXCHG.80).aspx) allows you to do this

Answer (score 0):

### outlook2ical

 has a VBMacro to export outlook calendar to iCal format.

You might check if its worth the time to port to C#.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm.. Just wondering if [Google Calendar Sync](http://dl.google.com/googlecalendarsync/GoogleCalendarSync_Installer.exe) lets you do this.
I havent got any shared calendar to try out.

Or have you tried that already?

Comment: That won't wprk. All events in your primary Google Calendar and your default Microsoft Outlook calendar are synced together. 

full article: http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=89955

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at VSTO ? (Visual Studio Tools for Office). 
This will provide APIs for the common Outlook items (Calendars etc). It's the C#/.Net version of various VBA admin APIs.